# How to write the test case in PHP and push into multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here i am having three field like name,email,mobile. here what i am doing means i writing the test case for those fields in PHP,lets take name field condition like

1. empty condition
2. name should not be number
3. name minimum 3 charector

suppose above conditions failed means i have to push to `Failed Condition` array,  i tried i am not getting my expected results,kindly any one update my code

> My code

```
    <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone)){

    // Scenario = 1
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $name)){
        $namevalidation['status'] = "Fail" ;
        $namevalidation['Failed Condition'][]['name'][]['Name should not be a number'] = "Condition Failed" ;

    }
    // Scenario = 2
    $namelength = strlen($name);

    if($namelength > 2){

    }else{
    $namevalidation['Failed Condition'][]['name'][]['Minimum Charector'] = "Condition Failed" ;
    }


    if(!empty($namevalidation)){
        echo json_encode($namevalidation);
    }

}else{
    $mandatory['status'] = "Fail" ;
    $mandatory['Error Message'] = "Mandatory fields mismatch";
    if(empty($name)){
    $mandatory['Required Fields'][] = "Name is mandatory";
    } 
    if(empty($email)){
    $mandatory['Required Fields'][] = "Email is mandatory";
    }
    if(empty($phone)){
    $mandatory['Required Fields'][] = "Phone is mandatory";
    }
    if(!empty($mandatory)){
    echo json_encode($mandatory);
    }
}


?>
```

> Expected Output

```
{
"status": "Fail",
"Failed Condition": [
    {
        "name": [
            {
                "Name should not be a number": "Condition Failed"
            },
            {
                "Minimum Charector": "Condition Failed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

> But i am getting out put like this

```
{
"status": "Fail",
"Failed Condition": [
    {
        "name": [
            {
                "Name should not be a number": "Condition Failed"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": [
            {
                "Minimum Charector": "Condition Failed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Where does the `12` come from in your Json? As I see it there is nothing that is the `12`. Where the `12` is your code does a `[]` which means start a new array and that means it should be 0. Something is missing from your code or the array is larger than you indicate. Is this inside of a loop? Is that what makes the 12?

Comment: @ Andreas, sorry i am not mentioned `12`, ok now i will tell `12` means i am giving the input value `name`

Comment: @ Andreas, check now i have edited my code, like instead of giving dynamic key `12` now i have changed static key as `name`

Comment: @ Andreas, you got my point

Comment: This replicates what you want, but not sure why you need the extra arrays. https://3v4l.org/qkEKv as I see it this looks cleaner. But you have to decide https://3v4l.org/QoEPB

Comment: @ Thanks i got my expected output

Comment: Is that a working way of doing it? I can post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `[]` in your code that creates new arrays instead of appending the previously created array.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone)){

    // Scenario = 1
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $name)){
        $namevalidation['status'] = "Fail" ;
        $namevalidation['Failed Condition'][0]['name'][]['Name should not be a number'] = "Condition Failed" ;

    }
    // Scenario = 2
    $namelength = strlen($name);

    if($namelength > 2){

    }else{
    $namevalidation['Failed Condition'][0]['name'][]['Minimum Charector'] = "Condition Failed" ;
    }


    if(!empty($namevalidation)){
        echo json_encode($namevalidation);
    }

}else{
    $mandatory['status'] = "Fail" ;
    $mandatory['Error Message'] = "Mandatory fields mismatch";
    if(empty($name)){
    $mandatory['Required Fields'][] = "Name is mandatory";
    } 
    if(empty($email)){
    $mandatory['Required Fields'][] = "Email is mandatory";
    }
    if(empty($phone)){
    $mandatory['Required Fields'][] = "Phone is mandatory";
    }
    if(!empty($mandatory)){
    echo json_encode($mandatory);
    }
}
```

However your current code creates different main structure of the Json if a different input is made.

Say the name is 'ab' then your code does not add the `$namevalidation['status'] = "Fail" ;`.

My suggestion is that you in "scenario 2" do a isset() check and if it's not set then you set it.

```
if($namelength > 2){

}else{
$namevalidation['Failed Condition'][0]['name'][]['Minimum Charector'] = "Condition Failed" ;
if(!isset($namevalidation['status'])) $namevalidation['status'] = "Fail" ;
}
```